# How does Riot decide which tier to put you in after the provisionals?

Tags: league-of-legends

So as we all know, we need to complete 10 provisional games at the start of a new season to get into a tier (Bronze, Silver, etc.).

Some people manage to win all their 10 provisional matches and get into only Bronze or Silver, whereas, some people only wins like half their provisionals and still get into Gold tier.

How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all based off your ELO, which is a hidden score Riot does not show you which it uses for matchmaking.

At the start of a new season your ELO gets reset back towards 1200:  ELO = (ELO-1200)/2+1200.

You then play 10 matches, with those matches having a larger effect on your ELO than a normal match.

At the end of the matches it places you into a league based on your ELO.

So this means that if you are completely new that season you start at 1200, but if you were diamond last season then you will be reset towards 1200, but you will still start higher than 1200 before you even start your placement matches.

Comment: Is there sources for this? Just asking...

Comment: @KimMinseo This is based off reading up on this (including official riot announcements) from a number of sources. I can't give you direct links as I haven't saved them but google should let you find them.

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge of League of Legends from friends, if it is your first time calibrating into ranked, then you will only be calibrated at about gold 3 (?). Assuming you've played solo and won all of your 10 calibration games for ranked.

This changes when lets say you play with a friend who is platinum. Lets say, for this example, you play with him until level 30 and you win all of your calibration games, you won't get gold 3 (assuming) but you would get a higher rank.

Again, this also can change if you have played ranked before. Lets say, in Season 1 I was ranked gold 3 (because I had one all of my games), next season I might be calibrated to Platinum because of my previous calibration (Assuming that I didn't become worse and won the majority of my games).